# Make Leaflet map background transparent

Tags: javascript, leaflet, transparency-opacity

How can I make the background of the Leaflet map transparent.  I see opacity controls from the layers, but not the map background.  Should the be changed just with plain CSS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hey plain CSS did the trick:

```
.leaflet-container {
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```css
.leaflet-container {
  background: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using the leaflet.extras package -- you can make the background white or transparent!

```
library(leaflet.extras)

mapname%>%

setMapWidgetStyle(list(background= "white"))
```

Comment: This question is about Javascript Leaflet.

Comment: @Jessie this is for `leaflet` on Javascript not `R`

Comment: I found this very useful, because I couldn't find an appropriate answer for R. Came up on google, problem solved. Thank you.